# Web scraping for a javascript rendered website using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please excuse if the question seems novice as i am very new to it, but I have tried it many ways but couldn't reach any solution.
I am trying to scrape this [website](https://speta.org/home/directory-of-members/?type=companies&category%5B%5D=corporate-member&sort=a-z) . Below is the code :-

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
urls = []
for i in range(1,5):
    pages = "https://speta.org/home/directory-of-members/?type=companies&category%5B%5D=corporate-member&pg={0}&sort=a-z".format(i)
    urls.append(pages)
Data = []
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless') 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =r"C:/XXXXXX/XXXXXXX/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
links=[]
for info in urls:
    browser.get(info)
    time.sleep(10)
    elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='1f-item 1f-item-default']/a")
    link = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elements]
    links.append(link)
print(links)
```

**Error :-**

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='1f-item 1f-item-default']/a"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=88.0.4324.104)
```

I am sure I am making a mistake in identifying correct tag herein,
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated !!

Thanks !!

Comment: for the  single element use browser.find_element_by_xpath and to find multiple elements  browser.find_elements_by_xpath, Its return list

Comment: @SamsulIslam _ It's giving an empty list even if i use,elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me.  to find multiple elements use `browser.find_elements_by_xpath` . Here i used `browser.find_elements_by_css_selector` its return list.
You can also use this xpath

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='c27-explore-listings']/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a")
```

It's also work.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
urls = []
for i in range(1,5):
    pages = "https://speta.org/home/directory-of-members/?type=companies&category%5B%5D=corporate-member&pg={0}&sort=a-z".format(i)
    urls.append(pages)
Data = []
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
links=[]
for info in urls:
    browser.get(info)
    time.sleep(10)
    elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.lf-item.lf-item-default a")
    # elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='c27-explore-listings']/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a")
    link = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elements]
    links.append(link)
print(links)
```